# C - error when attempting to pass /bin/ls to execvp

Tags: c, ls, execvp

I am working on a C program that needs to be able to execute certain commands using execvp, and I have implemented this with:

`execvp(arguments[0], arguments);`

where `arguments[]` is an array of stings. For the most part, my implementation works fine - e.g. if `arguments` is `{"touch", "somefile.txt"}` then the `touch` command is called as expected.

However, when I attempt to pass `ls` to execvp with arguments being something like `{"/bin/ls", "-a", "."}`, the ls function prints the directory listing as expected but also prints the error

`ls: cannot access GLIBC_2.0: No such file or directory`

I have no idea how to resolve this warning, and a google search has turned up nothing. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page of `execvp` says:

> The `execv()` and `execvp()` functions provide  an  array  of  pointers  to
>   null-terminated  strings  that represent the argument list available to
>   the new program.  The first argument, by convention,  should  point  to
>   the  filename  associated  with  the file being executed.  **The array of
>   pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.**

Comment: @Dave It is possible that after the `arguments` array a pointer to the string `GLIBC_2.0` followed in the data section by sheer accidence, so `ls` was trying to list that one too.