# how to use execvp--finding the file argument

Tags: c, unix, execvp

I wrote a test program to try and understand how to use execvp(), but I keep running into a problem. The relevant part of my code is:

```
...
printf("execute: 'ls -a'\n"); 
char *args[2];
args[0] = "/bin/ls";
args[1] = "ls";
args[2] = "-a";
...
} else if(pid == 0){ //child process
    if(execvp(*args, args) < 0) { //execute command
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: execution failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
...
```

Whenever I run, I get an error "/bin/ls: cannot access ls: No such file or directory". `which ls` tells me /bin/ls so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is it because the executable file isn't in my home directory but rather a projects file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issue here:

`args` is defined as a 2 element array, but you're putting in 3 elements, so you're writing past the end of the array.

The `args` array needs to have a NULL pointer as the last element, otherwise `execvp` won't know when it reaches the end of the argument list.

The first element in `args` should be the name of the program (this is what shows up in a `ps` listing), and subsequent elements should be the arguments.  The way it is now, you  have `ls` as the second element in the array, meaning it's the first argument to  the command `/bin/ls`.  So the `ls` command tries to find the file named `ls` in the current directory but can't.  This explains the error message you're getting.

With the fixes applied:

```
...
printf("execute: 'ls -a'\n"); 
char *args[3];
char *path = "/bin/ls";
args[0] = "ls";
args[1] = "-a";
args[2] = NULL;
...
} else if(pid == 0){ //child process
    if(execvp(path, args) < 0) { //execute command
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: execution failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good and correct answer, but I had to read it a couple of times before I picked up on your distinction between the "first element" of `args` and the "first argument" to the exec'ed command.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I made some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Same question as here [C - error when attempting to pass /bin/ls to execvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331733/c-error-when-attempting-to-pass-bin-ls-to-execvp)

You basically must terminate the array of pointers with a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I really think the code is

```
char *args[3];
args[0] = "/bin/ls";
args[1] = "-a";
args[2] = NULL;
```

Than

```
char *args[2];
args[0] = "/bin/ls";
args[1] = "ls";
args[2] = "-a";
```